# pandas filtering column names

Tags: pandas, data-science

I have this type of dataframe;

`A =  ["axa","axb","axc","axd","bxa","bxb","bxc","bxd","cxa".......]`

My question is I have this type of data but there are more than 350 columns and for example i need only 'c' including column names in new dataframe. How can i do that?

new dataframe columns should look like this;

`B =  A[["axc","bxc","cxa","cxb","cxc","cxd","dxc","exc","fxc".......]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for filter columns names with `c` by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df2 = df.filter(like='c')
```

Or use list comprehension for filter columns names:

```
df2 = df[[x for x in df.columns if 'c' in x]]
```

Comment: filter is working very fast and good

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using list comprehension:

```
new_df = df[[col for col in df.columns if 'c' in col]]
```